# Syntax for passing a component parameter based on a condition

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I am attempting to include a parameter in a component based on a condition, but I'm not sure of the syntax to use:

```
<Select @if (transaction.Id == 4)  { Value="1" }>
```

Full code snippet:

```
@foreach (var transaction in Transactions)
{
    <Select @if (transaction.Id == 4)  { Value="1" }>
        <SelectOption Value="1">Option 1</SelectOption>
        <SelectOption Value="2">Option 2</SelectOption>
    </Select>
}
```

So in short, I only want the Value parameter passed to the Select component when a condition is satisfied.  The Select Component is a custom component.

What is the correct syntax to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this using a ternary

```
<select value=@(transaction.Id ==4 ? "1":"")></select>
```

Nb: not sure if your select is a standard HTML select, as its starts with an uppercase S indicating that it's a component